# Which is better, save a website images on Amazon S3, Flickr or Picasa?

Tags: image, amazon-s3, flickr

I have a website and going to extend it, so users will upload their images on this website, i want to save users images in another storage service.

Users will save images and view them, and also share with others.

I know that i can do that using Amazon S3, Flickr or Picasa.

But i want to know which is better than which? which one should i use and why?

Based on your experiences, can you recommend one, or advice me if you a better service than those 3?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Image sharing websites like Flickr and Picasa do mention in their terms of service that you can only upload images that were created by yourself. So if users of your website would upload their images and you would put them in a Flickr or Picasa account created for your website, it would possibly conflict with the terms of service.

I guess it's therefore better to go with a file storage service like Amazon S3, which don't have these restrictions.

Answer (score 2):

I say use Amazon S3. Picasa and Flickr just aren't meant to serve as a storage mechanism for someone else's web app.

Answer (score 1):

Flickr is unlimited but has a 200MB upload limit a month.

Picasa has unlimited upload / month but has a 5GB total limit.

I don't have experience with Amazon S3 :)

Comment: Note Flickr now does not have an upload bandwidth limit

Answer (score 0):

I'd recommend Amazon S3.